# Optimal body repositioning with rotation, based on bezier curve

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

I have a turn-based 2D game where you control a spaceship and its movement is controlled by setting desirable position and direction for it. My task is to create an optimal path for its repositioning. There are no collisions and it can have any velocity from zero up to some limit. Overall, [it looks something like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOY8y.png).

Grey ship is your original position and yellow is final position. Red dots indicate a path built. It is built with a bezier curve and yellow dots on the ends of yellow lines are the control points, so-called anchors for smooth turning, so they kinda simulate approach vector.

[Destination point can be in any distance or direction from ship and can have any angle.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eL0E.png)

Since it can have any velocity, it can just rotate on place, then fly towards its destination coorinates and rotate after it arrives. But, first, it's not as fancy-looking as rotating mod-flight, but aslo consumes more time, i think. So i've decided that a ship needs to find an optimal arrival trajectory.

For it to work i added a fifth control point, its position is shown by third yellow point, not bound to anything. I calculate its position by taking a -1..1 multiplier in lerp function, where 0 is a direct midpoint between the two anchors and 1 is a third vertex in equilateral triangle. -1 is a triangle in opposite direction.

The only question is how to calculate a multiplier. I have three polar coordinates - original ship direction, desired ship direction and relative position between start and target coordinates (direction from start to target point). However, i'm kinda too bent on this thing already and i have a feeling i'm missing a stupidly easy solution.

I mostly tried different combinations between those angles, first mathematically, then blindly.
But then i've realized that there is different logic for optimal path depending on different relative position of points. So when your goal is in front of you, a simple angle difference between your final direction (minus starting direction) and relative position [works like a charm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZ4KY.png)

```
ad = (finDir - startDir + 360) mod 360;
dd = angle_difference(ad, relativeDir); //function returns -180..180 
multi = dd/180
```

However, when your goal is somewhat behind you, [it won't always work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFUl8.png). With such approach, there will be one breakpoint where angle difference reached 180 or -180 and jumps to the opposite side, so does the multiplier jump between -1 and 1, [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eQGa.gif)

It is good when your target is in front and you only need a breakpoint for 180 degree turn. But when target is behind, [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKs2b.png), you actually need a second breakpoint.
Also,
basically when your relative position is to your left, your multiplier always should be positive, 0..1 to be precise (or negative, depending on where your equal triangle faces, mine is shown as teal dot for multi=1), and to your right it's always negative. For example, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzIwE.png) it should be equal to zero, i think.

And then also there are [such cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kyo2F.png), where it's better to turn left to arrive to your right.

I think i've even messed up the explanation since the problem is quite simple itself since it's just three angles, cmon ._. and i've spent much more time on it so i'm here to ask if maybe i'm just being stupid about angle calculations or my overall solution can't work and such things should be made somehow else.

Also i'm quite sure i'm not nearly the first guy to do such a thing and there have to be tons of materials about this but i literally dunno how such task is called, and i hate to be an "i dunno how to google it" guy, but i guess i'm the one this time.

Comment: I know you said it's not as fancy looking, but what if instead of rotating the ship in place all the way at each end, you rotated the ship in place only in the cases where its orientation was in the 180-degree sector opposite the line segment, and then just to be perpendicular to the segment? It doesn't seem like flying in the wrong direction would be more efficient.

Comment: Yea, and that would be easier, but it's important to apply the biggest velocity possible, only slowing down when distance towards the point is smaller than full-speed rotation.
Think of it as it already has an acceleration from previous turn, so it needs more fuel to stop and rotate instead of slightly slowing down while turning.

Comment: Plus combat-wise it's better to be constantly moving rather than stay at one place rotating